# Owl Carousel 2.0 Randomize Button

Tags: owl-carousel

I am currently building a website for myself and I am using [Owl Carousel 2.0][1]. I really love this plugin for it's versatility but I am trying to add a 'custom' navigation button and because I am more of a designer and less of a programmer, I am having a hard time building out this feature.

I am trying to create a button that will randomly choose an image from the slider each time it is clicked. Specifically I would like to have the 'photo' part of my navigation utilize this function.

You can view the beginning result at http://photosorrentino.tumblr.com. Please let me know if you require any additional information. Thank you!

`$(document).ready(function() { //Sort random function function random(owlSelector){ owlSelector.children().sort(function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5; }).each(function(){ $(this).appendTo(owlSelector); });<br/> }<br/> var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); owl.owlCarousel(); // Go to the next item $('.wrap').click(function() { owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel'); }) $('.random').click(function(elem) { random(elem); }) });`

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: `//Sort random function
      function random(owlSelector){
        owlSelector.children().sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
        }).each(function(){
          $(this).appendTo(owlSelector);
        });`


This is the code I am looking to deal with and having trouble integrating with a clickable div.

Comment: Please update your question with this code.

Comment: @phts sorry about that, I am new to posting on stack but I constantly frequent for troubleshooting questions. Thank you!

Comment: can anyone advise on this issue?